# Windows Service running on System Account with User Data

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, appdata

I got a program which puts files into my Applications Appdata folder and a service which needs to read them an perform some action.

My problem is that, I cannot run the Service under the User account because then installutil ask me for credentials.
And I also cannot run it under the System Account, because then i cannot access the current Users Appdata

Comment: As long as the user has the "run as a service" right, it will work fine as the user. InstallUtil needs to be ran as admin to do the install, but the service doesn't require that

Comment: but i dont want the credentials prompt to appear

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now. You want to have the service ran as that user, but those user credentials are not available during install or some such restriction. What about granting folder rights to system for the directories in question? Are these programs yours or 3rd party (I.e. can you point them both to an alternate location?)